# Find ip from ip2location_db11 database

Tags: php, sql

i use ip2location_db11.CSV database to find ips detailed. its create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `ip2location_db11`(
`ip_from` INT(10) UNSIGNED,
`ip_to` INT(10) UNSIGNED,
`country_code` CHAR(2),
`country_name` VARCHAR(64),
`region_name` VARCHAR(128),
`city_name` VARCHAR(128),
`latitude` DOUBLE,
`longitude` DOUBLE,
`zip_code` VARCHAR(30),
`time_zone` VARCHAR(8),
INDEX `idx_ip_from` (`ip_from`),
INDEX `idx_ip_to` (`ip_to`),
INDEX `idx_ip_from_to` (`ip_from`, `ip_to`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

and with this details:

```
"16777216","16777471","AU","Australia","Queensland","Brisbane","-27.467940","153.028090","4000","+10:00"
```

cuz large list of ips all ip located with ip range in 2 columns (ip_from , ip_to)

how to find my ip from this table? i know this:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *
                      FROM ip2location_db11
                      WHERE ip = {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}
                      LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

But how to find my ips from this ip range in columns (ip_from , ip_to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the example data and judging by the column type for ip I would say that the ip has been transformed to an int using ip2long() ~ fine for ipv4 addresses, not so good for ipv6 I believe. So, your sql will need to account for the ip2long conversion and there is a little gotcha with large numbers in php so I'd suggest using sprintf also.

```
$ip = sprintf( '%u', ip2long( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) );
$sql= 'select * from `ip2location_db11` where `ip_from` >= '.$ip.' and `ip_to` <= '.$ip.' limit 1;';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple query

```
SELECT * FROM ip2location_db11 WHERE INET_ATON('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx') BETWEEN ip_from AND ip_to
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this:

```
$db = new PDO( "mysql:dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
) );
$sth = $db->prepare("
    SELECT *
    FROM ip2location_db11
    WHERE ? BETWEEN ip_from AND ip_to
    LIMIT 1
" );

$sth->execute( array( 
    array_reduce(
        explode(".", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ),
        function($carry,$in) { return ($carry *256) + intval( $in);}
    )
) );

$row = $sth->fetch( \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

I'm using PDO here, since the `mysql` extension is deprecated, and doesn't allow
parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

`INET_ATON(expr)` will convert the IP address to numeric value.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

SELECT *
FROM ip2location_db11
WHERE ip_from >= INET_ATON('$ip')
AND ip_top <= INET_ATON('$ip')
LIMIT 1
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton